# Fastest way to loop through an array in meteor js server side

Tags: meteor

I have a loop in my meteor application as below,

```
Meteor.Methods({
'sample':function(tasks){
    var i=0;
    var found=[];
    for(;i<tasks.length;i++){
       found.push(Tasks.findOne({_id:tasks[i]}));
    }
    return found;
  }
});
```

Actually this is working fine for me, still, Is there any other looping mechanism which is faster..??

Comment: https://jsperf.com/fastest-array-loops-in-javascript/2

Comment: It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site, but you might find better luck at [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their question requirements](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are more strict than this site.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use normal node module of node js in your meteor application.

Link : https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm

Comment: Awwww... You saved my day..!

Comment: Uh, what? OP asks for some kind of "fastest loop", you provide a link to an npm-integration package... and it gets accepted? Did you perhaps answer OP's comment on @TotalShaw answer?

Comment: in the case of async functionality and sending callback after the loop ends, this answer is good.

Comment: node js providing lots of functionality by the use of node modules, this can be integrated to meteor by above link which i posted as answer

Answer (score 2):

Your query could be written as follow:

`var result = Tasks.find({_id: {$in: tasks}}).fetch()`

this query would return an array of all tasks whose _id appears in tasks

Comment: still is there any module in meteor like async (npm module in node js)

Comment: @AjithPai Sorry, I don't know what do you ask exactly... I guess you could find packages in [atmosphere](https://atmospherejs.com/) like npm

Comment: Thank you for answering and contributing to Stack Overflow, however please take a second look at the question, for it seems to be off-topic according to the [help/on-topic]. Answering off-topic question make it look like it's okay to ask such questions - it's not. Off-topic questions might get closed and then deleted, which would nullify your contribution! Also OP accepted a completely irrelevant answer, so yep.